# change the structure of my array to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object

I'd like to change the structure of my array to object with a new key (name: "tree")

```
const myArray = [{"my color": "orange color", "my value":1},{"my color": "red color", "my value":2},etc];

const myObject = {name: "tree",myArray: [{"my color": "orange color", "my value":1},{"my color": "red color", "my value":2},etc]};
```

This function doesn't works well :

```
  const k = Object.keys;
  const myObject = k(myArray).map((k) => ({ name: "tree",  myArray: myArray[k] }))
```

;

Comment: if you wanna *change* it, why are you making it a constant?

Comment: `myObject = {name:"tree",myArray:myArray]` ? no need to copy each element unless needing to do a shallow copied array instead of a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const myArray = [{"my color": "orange color", "my value":1},{"my color": "red color", "my value":2},etc];
const myObject = { name: "tree", myArray: myArray }
```

This should do the trick. No need to loop over anything.

If you need a copy of your object instead of a reference, you can use the `spread operator` which is a new JavaScript feature and old browsers won't support it.

```
const myArray = [{"my color": "orange color", "my value":1},{"my color": "red color", "my value":2},etc];
const myObject = { name: "tree", myArray: [ ...myArray ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

your answer below

```
const myArray = [{ "my color": "orange color", "my value": 1 }, { "my color": "red color", "my value": 2 }, etc];
    var myObject = new Object();
    myObject.name = "tree";
    myObject.myArray = myArray;
    console.log(myObject);
```